# Set different environments in AWS Amplify

Tags: amazon-web-services, devops, aws-amplify

I am just getting started with AWS Amplify and after some research, I am still unable to set up the environments structure I want. I have a Reactjs app which I want to host there, my plan is to have 3 environments:

- Dev: this environment is to test new features. Every new branch I create is automatically deployed to this environment (no problem here, already implemented).
- Staging: Once new features are merged into master branch I would like to have them deployed here. This should work as a pre-production environment.
- Production: Once features in staging are tested, they should be released into Production with just 1 click (or an easy action). Also production should be always running with the latest released build of the project.

So, what's the problem exactly? So far I don't know how to have master pointing to 2 environments, meaning that it is either deployed in staging or production environment, and promoting from staging to production is rather tedious at the moment.

Is there any way to implement this workflow in Amplify? Thank you in advance for your help.

Comment: Wondering if you were able to implement that? currently looking into doing the same

Comment: @WasimAbuzaher I did not, sorry. Amplify may need some further development yet, I moved to Firebase.